# How to upload image to assets? Can I do it without adding paperclip?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

From what I read it seems I need a gem, like paperclip to upload my favicon image.

In **application.html.erb** I have:

```
<link href="favicon.ico" rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" />
```

Then under assets/images I created the file: favicon.ico

I just don't know what to put in the file to make the favicon work. Adding paperclip seems like a lot of work for one 16 pixel image.

Comment: Paperclip is for accepting uploads from your users, which is a really different scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need any gem for that... just add you `favicon` to the assets folder and add the following line to the application layout:

```
<%= favicon_link_tag 'favicon.ico' %>
```

docs: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/favicon_link_tag

Comment: I'm probably missing an obvious answer here, but how do I add the favicon to the assets folder? It's on my computer desktop as favicon (5).ico

Comment: Drag it and drop it into your `myrailsapp/app/assets/images` folder just like any other asset.

Comment: rename it to `favicon.ico` and copy it to the folder `yourproject/app/assets/images`